# how to create a report wihich inludes combinations of two related list under opportunity object

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type, joined-reports

I want to create a report with two related list's under my opportunity object, like i have milestone and customer success feedback related list, so i want to create a report which contains fields of both milestone and customer success feedback related list, with filter completed date or/and forcast date
Report for deadline completed or not.

Please help me, any one who knows this scenario please help me in detail.

Comment: This is a good question for the Salesforce Success Forum

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a Joined Report:
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_joined_format_concepts.htm

Essentially it's a report that combines TWO DIFFERENT report types.  As long as they have one object in common.  In this case, that would be your Opportunity.  So the opportunity record is the common thing across both reports and then you can pull in side-by-side any fields you need from either object.  They will be grouped by report type (so you can't mix them up in whatever order you want), but it's better than nothing.